# Android Espresso Library Import

Tags: android, android-listview, simpleadapter, android-espresso

I am trying to create a simple test that checks the data of the list view until it finds a corresponding entry. Here is the ListActivity:

```
package com.example.unittest.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class ListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView list;
    List<Map<String, String>> characterList;
    SimpleAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item " + i , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        characterList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        initList();
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, characterList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {"character"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void initList() {
        characterList.add(createItem("character", "Don"));
        characterList.add(createItem("character", "Sally"));
        characterList.add(createItem("character", "Betty"));
        characterList.add(createItem("character", "Joan"));
        characterList.add(createItem("character", "Freddy"));
        characterList.add(createItem("character", "Bert"));
        characterList.add(createItem("character", "Roger"));
        characterList.add(createItem("character", "Peggy"));
        characterList.add(createItem("character", "Dawn"));
        characterList.add(createItem("character", "Megan"));
        characterList.add(createItem("character", "Bob"));
        characterList.add(createItem("character", "Pete"));
    }

    private HashMap<String, String> createItem(String key, String name) {
        HashMap<String, String> month = new HashMap<String, String>();
        month.put(key, name);
        return month;
    }

}
```

In order to find the correct row, I am attempting to use onData to iterate through the array of maps in order to find the correct entry. Here is my test class:

```
package com.example.unittest.test;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

import com.example.unittest.app.MainActivity;
import com.example.unittest.app.R;

import org.hamcrest.Matchers;

import java.util.Map;

import static com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.Espresso.onData;
import static com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withContentDescription;
import static com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.allOf;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.anything;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasEntry;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.instanceOf;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;


/**
 * Created by user on 2014-04-21.
 */
public class EspressoInterfaceTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    public EspressoInterfaceTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        getActivity();
    }

    public void testButton1() {
        onView(withId(R.id.button)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.textview))                               // ViewMatcher
                .check(matches(withText("Pressed!")));              // ViewAssertion
    }

    public void testButton2() {
        onView(withId(R.id.button2))
                .perform(click());
        onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(Map.class)), hasEntry(equalTo("character"), is("Don")))
                .perform(click());

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I think I am importing the wrong Matchers because my onData the .perform method cannot be resolved and is shown in red. Is there a way to fix this? Will my onData call work? I was using https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSamples as a reference, but I can't seem to get it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You missed one bracket before perform action:

```
onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(Map.class)), hasEntry(equalTo("character"), is("Don"))))
                .perform(click());
```